# How to use React.Children.toArray with Typescript, when expecting only React.ReactElement and React.ReactElement[]

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My component takes only other a single component or multiple components as children. No string, no numbers, etc.

However, when I use `React.Children.toArray()` to convert it always to an array, it complains and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```js
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactElement | React.ReactElement[]
}

// inside component
const childArray: React.ReactElement[] = React.Children.toArray(children);
```

I get the following error:

```
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.ts(2322)
```

It does not seem like I'm able to pass down a type to `toArray()` since it's not a generic function, so I don't know where is the string coming from.

Any ideas?

Basically, the end result is to do an if else

```js
if (multiple components) return <SomeComponent>{children}</SomeComponent>
else <OtherComponent>{children}</OtherComponent>
```

Edit:

I intend to use the component this way:

```
<MyComponent>
  <Component />
</MyComponent>

or

<MyComponent>
  <Component />
  <Component />
</MyComponent>
```

Comment: Could you include what you are passing into the component?